# How do I deal with the fusionchart pie lines?

Tags: charts, fusioncharts, pie-chart

![fusionchart pie2D][1]

Hello, Guys
I want to know how to deal with the pie lines.
there are some datas out of the pie.
I want them into the circle.
but I don't know how to do it.
I already searched the documents of the fusioncharts but I couldn't find any solutions.
Could you help me please?

Comment: It is not possible to display the values within the pie.

Comment: You can set showValues to be zero and create annotations and position it the way you want. A similar example is shown here http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/77QP6/

Answer (score 0):

The pie lines or the colors in the pie chart represent the different types of data and their values.

While using [**Fusioncharts**](http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/pie-doughnut-charts/) you can use lot of events and well as features of pie charts, but the values can only be seen just close to the chart and not inside the pie.But still some features of the [**Fusioncharts**](http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/pie-doughnut-charts/) are :

- The charts gets rotated as much as you want.
- Is available in 2D as well as in 3D format.
- Interactive Rotation Capability.